# How to make multiple asynchronous network calls and upsert them at once?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I have an app with MVVM architecture. DB serves as the single source of truth. If the data is stale, I want to refresh the records by getting latest info from network.
I have to make a separate network call for each record in the DB. I need to upsert them all at once so that they all have same `updated_at` which would be nice for the next stale computation.

This is the method in the repository that refresh the records at the moment:

```
// locationApi.getLocation(...) is a suspend function in a Retrofit interface

private fun refresh(locations: List<LocationEntity>) {
    coroutineScope.launch(ioDispatcher) {
        locations.map {
            it.update(locationApi.getLocation(it.latitude, it.longitude))
        }.let {
            locationDao.upsertAll(it)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that API calls are done sequentially inside `map` and it takes a while to finish. How can I make API calls async and upsert the results at once? I have found the following solution but I would like to know possible solutions and their comparison.

**Solution: async + awaitAll**

```
private fun refresh(locations: List<LocationEntity>) {
    coroutineScope.launch(ioDispatcher) {
        locations.map {
            async { it.update(locationApi.getLocation(it.latitude, it.longitude)) }
        }.let {
            locationDao.upsertAll(it.awaitAll())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many db records are we talking about? Honestly this is going to be a huge headache when it comes to error handling, first I would ask whoever is responsible for api to add an endpoint that can handle list of locations because doing separate network call for each record is awful on both ends.

Comment: 20 max. It is a demo app so I didn't ask for it for now. Normally, I wrap network results to capture errors but I skipped it this time. The question has been bugging me for a while, I used this chance to ask right away :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple asynchronous network calls in Android using Kotlin and handle them collectively using Kotlin's coroutines along with the async function. To upsert the results at once, you can use **awaitAll** to collect the results and perform the upsert operation. Here is example

```
        class MainRepository(private val apiService: YourApiService, private val dao: YourDaoName) { 
    suspend fun fetchDataAndUpsert () {
     // Start multiple asynchronous network calls using coroutines
            val networkCall1 = async { apiService.getDataFromNetwork1() }
            val networkCall2 = async { apiService.getDataFromNetwork2() }

 // Await for both network calls to complete
        val response1 = networkCall1.await()
        val response2 = networkCall2.await()

        // Extract data from responses (assuming data is in response body)
        val dataFromNetwork1 = response1.body()
        val dataFromNetwork2 = response2.body()

        // Convert network data to entities for Room
        val dataEntities = mutableListOf<DataEntity>()
        dataFromNetwork1?.let { dataEntities.addAll(convertToEntity(it)) }
        dataFromNetwork2?.let { dataEntities.addAll(convertToEntity(it)) }

        // Upsert data into the Room database
        if (dataEntities.isNotEmpty()) {
            dao.upsertData(dataEntities)
        }
    }
```